# Show that this finite $p$-group is isomorphic to a product of two cyclic groups of the same order

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups, p-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian group of $p^{2n}$. Suppose for every $1 \le r \le n$, the subgroup $G_r=\{g \in G:g^{p^r}=e\}$ has order $p^{2r}$. Show that $G \cong \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$.

This is clearly a generalisation of the fact that a group of order $p^2$ is either a cyclic group or a product of two cyclic groups of order $p$. I am working on an exercise where $p^n$ is replaced by an arbitrary positive integer $M$, and I have decided to start with the case of $p$-groups (as the rest can be considered as an application of the Chinese remainder theorem). Here is how far I have gone.

We know that as an abelian $p$-group, $G$ can be written as
$$
G \cong \mathbb{Z}/p^{r_1}\mathbb{Z} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}/p^{r_s}\mathbb{Z}
$$
where $0<r_1 \le \dots \le r_s$ and $r_1+\dots+r_s=2n$. We also see $G_n=G$. Therefore every element in $G$ has order divisible by $p^n$, which implies that $p^{r_i}|p^n$ for all $i$, i.e. $0<r_1\le \dots \le r_s \le n$. If we can show that $r_1 \ge n$ or even $r_{s-1} \ge n$ then we are done. I am thinking about showing that $r_1<n$ gives rise to a contradiction, but I have not figured out where to start. I should not only use the fact that $G_n=G$. Perhaps I need to look at $G_{r_1}$.

How can I push it further? Or does my approach have some problems that should be fixed first?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Given any $r,s\geq 1$, can you compute the cardinality of $\{x \in \mathbb Z/p^s\mathbb Z, p^rx = 0\}$ ? If so, given any group $G$ of the form $G \cong \mathbb{Z}/p^{r_1}\mathbb{Z} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}/p^{r_s}\mathbb{Z}$, you may compute the cardinality of $G_r$ for any $r\geq 1$ depending on the $r_i$'s. If you make the assumption that $G_r$ has cardinality $p^{2r}$ for all $1\leq r \leq n$, you will obtain some conditions on the $r_i$'s which will lead you to the result.

Comment: Seems like you can work by induction on $n$ by considering $G/G_1$.

Comment: @Suzet The cardinality is $\sum_{k=0}^{r}\phi(p^k)=p^r$. It follows that $G_{r_1}$ has order $sr_1=2r_1$, which implies that $s=2$. Therefore $G$ is a product of two cyclic $p$-groups. Each component's order has to be $p^n$ otherwise we wouldn't have $G_n=G$. So we are done. Do you think my steps are valid? Thanks.

Comment: I think my latest comment can be simplified further: $r_1+r_2 =2n$ but $r_1 \le r_2 \le n$. The only integral solution to this equation is $r_1=r_2=n$.

Comment: To be a little bit more precise, the cardinality of $\{x\in \mathbb Z/p^i\mathbb Z, p^rx = 0\}$ is $p^r$ if $r\leq i$, and $p^i$ if $r > i$ (I changed the exponent $s$ in my first comment to $i$, in order to avoid confusion). Otherwise, your steps are valid!